# Android Studio - Internationalizing an app / support foriegn languages

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

I am trying to internationalize my android app. I'm using Android Studio, and I know there is a way to have android studio generate the required string.xml files to edit in another language (a friend did this and it displays the country's flag next to the string file name). However, I do not know how to navigate Android studio to do this. Would anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your strings.xml > click the Open Translations Editor link. >Click on the world icon.